# Why does a wallet user need to sign a message to login?

Tags: ethers.js, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, signature

We all know how Ethereum signing works for user authentication. MetaMask asks you to sign, you sign it and application's server validates it and, if true, allows you to use services.

Assume that in my application's index.html, I have the following code:

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []).then(accounts => {
   const address = accounts[0];
   // send this address to my application server, put it in JWT 
   // and authenticate the user.
})
```

What this code does is opens the MetaMask, asks me to agree (but doesn't make me sign anything) and, if I agree, `accounts` (my address) is given to the server.

My question is: why wouldn't this be enough? Why do we need Eth signing? Can you tell how an attacker would trick my application that uses the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why wouldn't this be enough ?

Because anyone can all you API endpoint with any address they want.

Comment: " server only allows requests from my specific web client " that's not how Internet works